# Android Spinner set item selected listener is calling infinitely

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, arraylist

I have taken 3 Spinner in My Activity. Each Spinner is filled with the same data but in some different way.

Let me explain it with below example.

My main list consists of data like this: a, b, c, d, e, and so on.

So when I see the Spinner 1, it should select the value a (this value should not be listed in the 2nd and 3rd spinner and vice versa).

E.g. Spineer 1 value : a, d, e (not b and c)
  Spineer 2 value :: b, d, e (not a and c)
  Spineer 3 value :: c, d, e (not a and b)

What my problem is:

When I select the value from the spinner 1, it's not getting selected and by seeing the Android Logs, it goes in infinite state.
Same problem happens with Spinner 2 and Spinner 3.

Below is the code which I have tried.

```
public class SpinnerDemo extends Activity {
    private Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3;
    ArrayList<String> MAinArrayList;
    ArrayList<String> TempList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.final_sp);

        sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

        TempList = new ArrayList<String>();
        MAinArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        MAinArrayList.add("a");
        MAinArrayList.add("b");
        MAinArrayList.add("c");
        MAinArrayList.add("d");
        MAinArrayList.add("e");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, MAinArrayList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //  dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        sp1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        final String strA = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        TempList.addAll(MAinArrayList);
        for (int i = 0; i < TempList.size(); i++) {
            if (TempList.get(i).equals(strA)) {
                TempList.remove(strA);
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < TempList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Templist " + (i) + "==>" + TempList.get(i));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TempList);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //  dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        sp2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
        //        ArrayList<String> TempList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        //        TempList1.addAll(MAinArrayList);

        //        if (TempList.size() > 0) {
        //            TempList.clear();
        //        }
        //TempList.addAll(MAinArrayList);

        final String strB = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();
        final ArrayList<String> TempList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        TempList1.addAll(TempList);
        System.out.println("Templist1 ADDDED" + TempList1);

        for (int i = 0; i < TempList1.size(); i++) {
            if (TempList1.get(i).equals(strB)) {
                TempList1.remove(strB);
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("removed templist " + TempList1);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < TempList1.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("TempList3 " + (i) + "==>" + TempList1.get(i));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TempList1);
        dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //  dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        sp3.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);

        sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ArrayList<String> TempSP2 = new ArrayList<String>();
                TempSP2.addAll(MAinArrayList);
                System.out.println("TempSP2 ==>" + TempSP2);
                String strC = sp3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String strA = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();

                for (int i = 0; i < TempSP2.size(); i++) {
                    if (TempSP2.get(i).equals(strC)) {
                        TempSP2.remove(strC);
                        break ;
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < TempSP2.size(); i++) {
                    if (TempSP2.get(i).equals(strA)) {
                        TempSP2.remove(strA);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("removed TempSP2 strAC" + TempSP2);

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpinnerDemo.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TempSP2);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                //  dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                sp2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ArrayList<String> TempSP3 = new ArrayList<String>();
                TempSP3.addAll(MAinArrayList);
                System.out.println("TempSP3 ==>" + TempSP3);
                String strA = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String strB = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();

                for (int i = 0; i < TempSP3.size(); i++) {
                    if (TempSP3.get(i).equals(strA)) {
                        TempSP3.remove(strA);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < TempSP3.size(); i++) {
                    if (TempSP3.get(i).equals(strB)) {
                        TempSP3.remove(strB);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("removed TempSP3 strAb" + TempSP3);

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpinnerDemo.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TempSP3);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                //  dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                sp3.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ArrayList<String> TempSP1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                TempSP1.addAll(MAinArrayList);
                System.out.println("TempSP1 ==>" + TempSP1);
                String strB = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String strC = sp3.getSelectedItem().toString();

                for (int i = 0; i < TempSP1.size(); i++) {
                    if (TempSP1.get(i).equals(strB)) {
                        TempSP1.remove(strB);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < TempSP1.size(); i++) {
                    if (TempSP1.get(i).equals(strC)) {
                        TempSP1.remove(strC);
                        break;
                    }
                }


                System.out.println("removed TempSP1 strBC" + TempSP1);

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpinnerDemo.this,                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TempSP1);                       dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                //  dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                sp1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I wanted to fill the 3 spinners as taken above with unique values but main problem is the data is already set but then again m not able to select any item and loop goes in infinitie times

Comment: hii @Sabeeh please check i hav changed and explained briefly

Comment: You have put all codes in one single method onCreate() and also you have called spinner 1 selected text and apply functionality therefore it will continue infinity to check.. better is separate entire code and apply selection functionality in one another method and call it on spinner selection

Comment: NO its of no use though i create other method it goes to infinite state

Comment: At the first place you should use `iterator` instead of `for` as you are making loop on the list and same time you are also deleting item from the list.